# How can i find which Android API versions does OkHttp 3.14 supports?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am using OKHTTP 3.14 and my device has API 24 (android 7.0) , does that support it?
Because when making http requests in devices with higher lever it works perfectly fine but not in the device with API level 24.

**EDIT:
When I run this function below, it works in newer API than 24 but when I run it in my older device with API level 24 it throws an exception:**

```
private String get_OKHttp3Response(String _uri) {
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
String strResp = "";
try {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(_uri).build();
    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    }
    strResp = response.body().string();
    if (!strResp.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        return strResp;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println( "get_OKHttp3Response Exception: " + e.getMessage() );
    return "";
}
```

};

**And I get this message when the exception is thrown:**

```
Exception: null
```

Comment: OkHttp works on Android 5.0+ (API level 21+) and on Java 8+. (from github README) https://github.com/square/okhttp/. The lastest version is `4.7.2`, maybe you can try updating it

Comment: You haven't specified what error you're getting, or shown us the relevant code. I have used OkHttp 3.14 successfully on Android 5 up to Android 11.

Comment: @Michael see the edited question, I posted the code there.

Comment: Include a stacktrace for the exception please.

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/security/

Answer (score 1):

https://square.github.io/okhttp/security/

June 25th, 2020

```
╔═════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Version ║    Supported     ║                                   Notes                                    ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4.x     ║ ✅                ║ Android 5.0+ (API level 21+) and on Java 8+.                               ║
║ 3.14.x  ║ Until 2020-06-30 ║                                                                            ║
║ 3.12.x  ║ Until 2021-12-31 ║ Android 2.3+ (API level 9+) and Java 7+. Platforms may not support TLSv1.2 ║
╚═════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```